# How can I transfer [content] from one page to another?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

There is a link on the page of the MODx site. By clicking on this link I turn to another page. Want to transfer all [content] from the first page to a new page and display it. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Do you just want both pages to use the same content?

Comment: Solution: http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,64009.msg362155.html

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MODx are you using? Evolution or Revolution? Also a link to page you are  referring to would help.

In MODx manager if you right click on a resource (page) there is an option to create a duplicate page. You can link to this copy from the first page.

However I suspect this isn't what you're asking so more details please if you need a better response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [content] to a template and using the template in all pages you create.